# Merging two lists of dicts and updating keys as a result

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dicts, explaining someone and their role, e.g., below L1 shows drivers indicated by D in their role, and L2 show packers indicated by P in their role:

```
L1 = [
    {'D': 'Jim Jones'}, 
    {'D': 'Tom Jones'},
    {'D': 'Bob Jones'}
]

L2 = [
    {'P': 'Jim Jones'},
    {'P': 'Bob Jones'}
]
```

I want to consolidate the list of dicts so that the key is a consolidated key of their role, e.g.,:

```
L3 = [
    {'DP': 'Jim Jones'}, 
    {'D': 'Tom Jones'},
    {'DP': 'Bob Jones'}
]
```

Order does not matter and this could be a new list or could be done in place

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This should get the job done:**

```
>>> scratch = {v : k for d in L1 for k, v in d.items()}
>>> for d in L2:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if v not in scratch:
                scratch['v'] = ''
            scratch[v] += k

>>> result = [{v: k} for k, v in scratch.items()]
>>> result
[{'DP': 'Jim Jones'}, {'D': 'Tom Jones'}, {'DP': 'Bob Jones'}]
```

**Here's what it is doing:**

*Step 1)* Build a *scratch* dictionary with the *name* as the key:

```
scratch = {'Jim Jones': 'D', 'Tom Jones': 'D', 'Bob Jones': 'D'}
```

*Step 2)* Loop over the names in *L2*, then lookup the name in *scratch* and update its value.

```
scratch['Jim Jones'] += 'P'
```

*Step 3)* Turn the scratch dictionary back into a list of dictionaries:

```
result = [{'DP': 'Jim Jones'}, {'D': 'Tom Jones'}, {'DP': 'Bob Jones'}]
```

**Key to solving the problem**

The core idea is that the names should be keys in a single dictionary.  That makes it easy to do lookups and updates.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Doesn't this fail if L2 has names not present in L1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming names are unique, you really want the dictionary to go the other way (i.e. from names to roles) since otherwise the structure doesn't really make sense. If you do that, then instead of having a list of dictionaries each with a single person, you can just use *one* dictionary to hold all your data.

It's pretty trivial to convert your lists like so:

```
D1 = {name: role for record in L1 for (role, name) in record.items()}
D2 = {name: role for record in L2 for (role, name) in record.items()}
```

Now you can combine them together easily based on the keys:

```
for k, v in D2.items():
    D1[k] = D1.get(k, '') + v
```

Which gives you:

```
D1 = {'Tom Jones': 'D', 'Bob Jones': 'DP', 'Jim Jones': 'DP'}
```

I'd recommend just keeping the dictionary structure since it's much easier to use, but you can also convert it back into your list format easily if you want:

```
L3 = [{role: name} for name, role in D1.items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This one also works:

```
L1 = [
    {'D': 'Jim Jones'}, 
    {'D': 'Tom Jones'},
    {'D': 'Bob Jones'}
]

L2 = [
    {'P': 'Jim Jones'},
    {'P': 'Bob Jones'}
]

l1={}
for i in L1:
    print(list(i.keys())[0],list(i.values())[0])
    l1[list(i.values())[0]]=list(i.keys())[0]

l2={}
for i in L2:
    print(list(i.keys())[0],list(i.values())[0])
    l2[list(i.values())[0]]=list(i.keys())[0]

l1l2={}
for i in set(l2).union(set(l)):
    l1l2[i] = l.get(i,"")+l2.get(i,"")
l1l2_list = [{value:key} for key,value in l1l2.items()]
```